# how to create link in OSCommerce registration and then return to linked page?

Tags: php, redirect

i have a link in my navbar, which redirects the user to the login page(see code below). after the login-registration is completed. i would like them to be forwarded to the link, but right now it takes them back to the home page.

```
        // if the customer is not logged on, redirect them to the login page 
    if (!tep_session_is_registered('customer_id')) { 
    // Not logged in 
    tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_LOGIN, '', 'SSL')); 

}
```

i have tried to locate the code on the login page but nothing there looks familiar to me.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're using OS Commerce, right? I have little experience with OS Commerce, but I do have lots of experience with PHP. Here's something I would try this:

```
// if the customer is not logged on, redirect them to the login page 
if (!tep_session_is_registered('customer_id')) { 
    // Add session variable to redirect after login
    $_SESSION["redirect_after_login"] = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URl'];

    // Not logged in
    tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_LOGIN, '', 'SSL')); 
}
```

Then in your login execution, you could put something like this:

```
// Redirect if needed
if ( !empty($_SESSION["redirect_after_login"]) ) {
    header( 'Location: ' . $_SESSION["redirect_after_login"] );
}
```

Of course, depending on how OS Commerce works, you might need to add some more code to avoid an infinite loop, or to tighten security for the redirect... but this should get your close to what you need.